# How can I sync client side JS with AWS lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I've been reading about the new AWS Lambda technology and I have been trying some of their examples.  What I'd really like to be able to do is to serve new content out to clients when we upload a new data file to S3, but its not clear to me if or how I can do that.

I can see that I can run a script in lambda to log changes to S3, but how can I sync those changes up with a client script running in a browser. Is that possible?

Obviously I can poll the bucket object and show new content when it changes, but is there a way to push the data out when it changes the way node.js would? Then I wouldn't need to be constantly hitting it, when it's not changing.

Comment: At first I was thinking Cognito sync, but in trying to make a proof-of-concept I hit some roadblocks. So I'm going to propose something a bit crazier: a [webhook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook). On your backend server, implement an endpoint that will be called by the Lambda function...it will basically be saying, "hey, there's new data in S3!" At that point your server can push an event to clients and the client can poll (once) for the new data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there can really be any sort of push mechanism at work.  Push requires a server listening for responses.  Which means that technically the only way this could happen is for each client to have a service running that is listening on a tcp port.  In the case of mobile clients, they really are listening for SMS messages.

In most cases, push is still actually a pull at different level of the stack.  Even in the top level application the code may allow for a push paradigm, but if we look at the code one level lower it could be a pull.

Take for instance, if you did design the periodic JS script that would query S3 or lambda or updates.  The client UI wouldn't know it was doing that and so it would seem like a push to them; that magically data was streamed to their client, the same way a streaming video might work.

I would suggest biting the bullet, and setting up a cache in API Gateway with an expected TTL on S3 changes, and then have the client query that resource.

Comment: It was a while ago that I posted the question, but node.js actually can *push* using websockets. Meteor (a node.js based framework) does this automatically. There are also some new HTML5 technologies, such as *service workers* that could probably accomplish this.